# Writing an exact equation for Matlab differential equation

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm having trouble writing an exact equation for this matlab differential problem. I'm using the Forward Euler, Backward Euler, and Crank-Nicolson method. A friend hinted as to how to write the exact solution yet I'm still having trouble. Currently my error is "Matrix Dimensions must agree". I've tried doing some trial and error but nothing has come out to work so far. Error is on the second to last line. Could someone guide me towards the right direction for the exact solution equation?

```
clear;                                 % clears all memory
clc;                                   % clears Command Window screen
close all;                             % closes all open figure windows 

for input_dt = 1:1:3
    prompt = 'enter dt: ';


% 1. Initialize
dt          =  input(prompt);          % choose delta t
t_start     = 0;                       % starting time
t_end       = 50;                       % end time
nstep       = ( t_end - t_start ) / dt;    
x           = zeros(2,1);
y           = zeros(2,1);
z           = zeros(2,1);
b           = zeros(2,1);
I           = eye(2);                       
all_t       = ( 1 : nstep) * dt;
all_Euler_x = zeros( nstep, 2);
all_exact = zeros( nstep, 2);
all_Euler_y = zeros( nstep, 2);
all_Euler_z = zeros( nstep, 2);
initial_displacement = 0.5;
initial_velocity = 1.0;

% 1.2 System Characteristics
m        = 1.0;
c        = 0.05;
k        = 4.0;
A(1,1) = 1.0 ; A(1,2) = 0.5;
A(2,1) = -k/m; A(2,2) = -c/m;

x(1) = initial_displacement;
x(2) = initial_velocity;


% 2. Forward Euler time integration
for n = 1 : nstep     
    x = x + dt * (A * x + b);     
    all_Euler_x (n, :) = x;                  
end

y(1) = initial_displacement;
y(2) = initial_velocity;

for n = 1 : nstep
    y = (I - dt * A) \ (y + dt * b);
    all_Euler_y (n, :) = y;
end

z(1) = initial_displacement;
z(2) = initial_velocity;

for n = 1 : nstep
    z = 0.5*(y + x); %Crank-Nicolson
    all_Euler_z (n, :) = z;
end


%3. Compute the exact solution

%3.1 Parameters needed to compute the exact solution
c_c      = 2.0 * sqrt (k*m);
zeta     = c / c_c;
omega_n  = c_c / (2.0 * m );
c1       = (initial_velocity + zeta * omega_n * initial_displacement) / (omega_n * sqrt (1.0 - zeta^2));     
c2       = initial_displacement;

%3.2 exact solution
for n = 1 : nstep
    t = n * dt;
    all_exact (n,1) =  all_exact - all_Euler_x / all_Euler_y / all_Euler_z; %Error on this line
end
```

Comment: Indicate at which line you receive that error

Comment: @Dan edited. Thank you.

Comment: `all_Euler_x / all_Euler_y / all_Euler_z;` this is farily suspicious. Are you trying to doi matrix division (i.e. matrix multiple with the inverse) or elementwise division? Either way I suggest you use brackets. Also `all_exact (n,1) =  all_exact - ....` is problematic because the dimensions will definitely not match as `all_exact (n,1)` is a scalar and `all_exact` is the whole matrix...

Comment: @dan I'm trying to do elementwise, I'll see if with brackets things change. Thank you!

Comment: Elementwise division is `./` not `/`.

Comment: Using ./, this is the error I get "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts". Always on the same line.

Comment: because `all_exact (n,1)` is a scalar... it makes no sense. You're trying to stuff an entire matrix into a single one of it's elements. Obviously you can't do that.